# Convert Textbox value to a double

Tags: vb.net

### I have Textbox1.Lines

```
25.0
25.0
25.0
25.0
25.0
25.0
25.0
25.0
25.0
25.0
Dim value2 as double = 0.4
Dim lines As String() = Textbox1.Lines
lines = Val(lines(here is a line code loop)) + val(value2)
Textbox1.Lines = lines
```

how do I make this code work? it only calculates my integer, for example if it were `255.5`, it only displays `255`.

how can i transform this textbox, to calculate doubles, for example `25.4 + 25.7 = 30.1`

I have to calculate the value of the line it has (ie `25.0`) + the new value, if it is `0.4` then it will display `25.4` , Unfortunately, my Textbox doesn't know how to do this, and I don't know how to transform it so that I can read the values ​​correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of the VisualBasic methods i suggest VB.NET. Use `Double.Parse` to parse the strings of each line to a `Double`, then add the fix value `value2`and use `ToString` to convert them back to string:

```
Dim invalidLines = From line in Textbox1.Lines
                   Where Not Double.TryParse(line.Trim(), Nothing)
If invalidLines.Any() Then
    ' Inform user that he should enter numeric values only '
    Return
End If

Dim lineValues = From line in Textbox1.Lines
                 Select (Double.Parse(line.Trim()) + value2).ToString()
Textbox1.Lines = lineValues.ToArray()
```

You need to add `Imports System.Linq`.

Comment: It would be more performant to use `Any` when getting the value for `invalidLines`. E.g. `Dim invalidLines = TextBox1.Lines.Any(Function(line) Not Double.TryParse(line.Trim(), Nothing))`

Comment: @David: Why? The code is basically the same, it's using deferred execution and stops at the first non-parsable line. Also i dont like method syntax for newbies in Linq, it should be readable, otherwise there's no need to use LINQ at all. But thanks for the hint with `Nothing` as second argument in TryParse, i was wondering how to make it inline like in C#. Edited my answer

Comment: My understanding is that the underlying loop in Any will exit once the first condition is met.

Comment: @David: Yes, exactly as with my approach using query syntax with two statements. The `Any`-method executes the query.

Comment: I guess that makes sense since the IEnumerable wouldn’t be enumerated until you called the Any method. I retract my original statement.